# Layover: Dubai or Doha

Tags: layovers, dubai, qatar, doha

I'm going to book a flight to Tokyo and I have to choose between

- Emirates, which stops in Dubai from 6.15 am to 2.15 am
- Qatar Airways, which stops in Doha form 4.30 am to 12.30 am (20 hours)

  1. I would like to visit one of the cities. What do you suggest me? I would prefer to see not only big buildings but also some traditional Arabic stuff.
  2. Is it easy for an Italian to get a visa at the airport? How much does it cost?
  3. Will I find some problem due to the fact that I'll be there on Friday?

Comment: I personally had a stopover in Doha, it was overnight and I was not sure if it was easy to get a visa so I did not try, but the airport is correctly equipped (there is a nap room), but it is cold (A/C is used too intensively). It happened 5 years ago so it might have changed a bit.

Comment: Last year I had a stopover in Doha. From what I understand there was a makeover on the main terminal so we arrived in the temporary "main" terminal. The terminal was clean but couldn't get a nice food there. Not sure whether the renovation of the main terminal has completed or not.

Comment: Just let you know that Dubai metro open at 2pm on Friday.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Doha

- **Transit Visa**: Not required..
- **Visa On Arrival**: You can have VOA if you want to go outside the airport in DOH for $30.
- Airport is nice and full facilities are available (duty free, food, place to sleep...etc).
- The city is nice with lots of activities. I suggest visiting **The Museum of Islamic Art**. Doha has many malls and modern shopping centers.

### Dubai

- **Transit Visa**: Not required.
- **Visa On Arrival**: You can have VOA if you want to go outside the airport in DXB for
  Free.
- Airport is huge and one of the best in the world. full facilities are available (duty free, food, place to sleep...etc).
- Dubai is the best city in the middle east, you will not find it difficult to find nice places to visit.

---

UAE and Qatar both are Arab countries so you will see Arabian stuff definitely everywhere you go.

Regarding Friday, no you will not find any problem. In both Qatar and UAE the weekend is Fridays and Saturdays. All places will be open except for government offices.

FYI, the visa information was intended for **Italian** citizens. For other nationalities please read [this for UAE](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx) or [this for Qatar](http://www.qatarembassy.net/visa.asp).

Comment: Does the Dubai visa allow me to visit the city both on the way to Tokyo and the way back?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the same VOA for the next time you come to DXB?

Comment: Yes! I mean, I want to use it the first time when I will be moving to Tokyo, and a second time 10 days later, when I will be coming back to Italy.

Comment: Well, I do not think so... but why worry? it is free and with no requirements..

Comment: because I will have 7 hours of stop on the way to Tokyo and 20 hours on the way back! So if possible, I would like to visit Dubai twice.